# How to achieve this unwrap?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

My problem is that I downloaded an fbx file and it already came with an unwrap uv map, the case is that I modified the body of the model that I downloaded in blender and when I did the uv unwrap, try to select some edges and check the seam , coincided with the original uv unwrap and the png, but the shape of the unwrap is different, different from the original, I would like to know if there is any way to solve it, I like the shape of the hands of the original, and I want to use the base png that gives the color to the original model, and modify it in photoshop and place it for my new model, do not modify the hands (in case there are doubts).
Original and what i want [image]
What I have: [image]

Sorry for my bad English, my level of blender is also a little basic.

---

**Doubt, my big problem:**
Quite apart from this question, will there be any other easier way to put all my textures (base color and image) together in a single uv map .png without doing it again as I try to do it now?

What happened is that I downloaded this fbx file. (I am talking about above) I modified it in blender and I did it with different bases of colors and images, and when I finished it I needed all the parts to be in one .png uv map and I did not know how to do it (maybe I should do the unwrap first and the textures later, but I did not know much about blender so I did it my way, but to upload this file to a page I need all the textures and colors to be of a single image, something like this for example - attached image ).
[image]

When I selected everything, and made uv unwrap all the textures were combined (images and base colors), each uv island had a different position, one on top of the other and I did not know how to put the textures together in an image, I want my uv unwrap of all my I model this in a single image, I heard about baking, I know very little about blender so this was very difficult for me.
So I created a copy of my file, and then deleted all the textures (all my effort and now to restart everything: / sad). Now I try to unwrap the entire model with my modifications and then put all my textures (images and base colors) on it by modifying them in Photoshop with some parts of the original png - from the fbx file I downloaded - which have good textures like hands and face ( but the unwrap of the hands does not come out the same as the original, this is my first doubt). If you have the solution to this problem (my second question, I am talking about this last paragraph) you can also share it, but if you do not have it, you can answer the question you came to answer (which is the main one).

Thanks in advance for reading. And again, sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes I guess the solution for all your problems is to bake, you need to follow some tutorials, you'll easily find some on Youtube

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have three objects, but to bake my objects must be joined (that's what I understood, do ctrl + j and that, if I'm wrong correct me) but I don't want this to happen, I have three objects that must be separated. I don't know if there is a way to bake without putting my objects together. Maybe I didn't see a good tutorial.

Comment: Select all your objects (A + B + C), duplicate them, join the duplications to make one unique object (let say D). Unwrap this new object (Smart UV Project mode), give it a new material with a new image texture, don't plug its Image Texture node in the Diffuse for the moment. Now select ABC, shift select D at the end, and bake with these options activated: Bake Type > Diffuse, Direct + Indirect (if you don't want any shadow), Selected to Active. Press Bake. It should bake the 3 objects materials into one. Now for D material you can plug the Image Texture into the Diffuse to see the result.

Comment: Join the duplications with the original ?, I mean I have A, B and C duplicate and now I have A1 B1 and C1, these three together with the original three? I wish I could better understand your answer because I feel that you are giving me the solution I need, when you say "give it a new material with a new image texture" it means that when in edit mode I should open a new image, that is black, right?  By doing this I will keep my textures right? I mean, in the end won't I have to do my textures in photoshop adjusting them to the new unwrapped uv?

Comment: no, don't join the duplications with the original, join the duplications together. And create a new image in the UV Editor, the one that you'll give to this new object and that will receive the bake.

Comment: I'm going to try it, but first I must fix my file but for some reason the faces are missing, they are there because I can select them but I cannot give them color, they are transparent, invisible or whatever: /, this of the bake I will try later , will there be some way to communicate with you through another site?, you are the only one who has helped me and provided this information, I am very clumsy with blender, do not answer if it bothers you, anyway thanks.

Comment: if the conversation is too long it will automatically switch to a chat page  ;)

Comment: I made shift + D to my three objects (A, B, C), I duplicated them and joined each other with ctrl + j, then in uv editing, all my new object D (a + b + c = D), I selected D (the new object) and then I pressed UV and unwrap, but as I commented before, my objects have textures, when I did that unwrap all my textures were combined.

Comment: Go into the material list of D, delete all materials, give it a new material with a blank image texture plugged into a Diffuse, then select A, shift select B and C, then D at the end, then Bake with the following options: Type > Diffuse, Direct & Indirect, Selected to Active. Click on the Bake button. Take a look to the image texture, it should now be correctly textured.